# bed file merge book-end features only if same name in column 4

Tags: bed, bedtools

I have a bed file where some entries have the same name in column 4 but are book-ended in coordinates, e.g. see below:

```
chr1    0       10000   LOC101929784::chr1:13201-13800::E1
chr1    10000   10600   LOC101929784::chr1:13201-13800::XYZ
chr1    10600   10800   LOC101929784::chr1:13201-13800::E1
chr1    10800   12000   DDX11L1::chr1:11868-14409.E1
chr1    12000   12200   DDX11L1::chr1:11868-14409.E1
chr1    12200   13000   DDX11L1::chr1:11868-14409.E1
chr1    13000   13200   DDX11L1::chr1:11868-14409.E1
chr1    13200   15800   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    15800   16000   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    16000   18200   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    18200   18400   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    18400   23000   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    23000   23400   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    23400   24000   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    24000   24200   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    24200   25200   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    25200   25800   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    25800   26200   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    26200   26400   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    26400   27000   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    27000   27600   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    27600   27800   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    27800   29600   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    29600   30800   MIR1302-2HG::chr1:29553-31109.E1
chr1    30800   31400   MIR1302-2HG::chr1:29553-31109.E1
```

I would like to apply an operation that seems to me is a mix of `bedtools merge -d 0` and `bedtools groupby`, but I can't figure out what's the combination.

For example, the 4 entries with `DDX11L1::chr1:11868-14409.E1` I would like merged as they are book-ended, same with the `WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1` entries and the `MIR1302-2HG::chr1:29553-31109.E1` entries. There are two `LOC101929784::chr1:13201-13800::E1` entries, but I don't want to merge them because they are not book-ended, since they are separated by `LOC101929784::chr1:13201-13800::XYZ`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{if($1==lchrom && $4==lname && $2 == lend) {lend = $3}else{if(lchrom) {print lchrom, lstart, lend, lname;}; lchrom=$1; lstart=$2; lend=$3; lname=$4}}END{print lchrom, lstart, lend, lname}' foo.bed > new.bed
```

That produces:

```
chr1    0   10000   LOC101929784::chr1:13201-13800::E1
chr1    10000   10600   LOC101929784::chr1:13201-13800::XYZ
chr1    10600   10800   LOC101929784::chr1:13201-13800::E1
chr1    10800   13200   DDX11L1::chr1:11868-14409.E1
chr1    13200   29600   WASH7P::chr1:14403-29570.E1
chr1    29600   31400   MIR1302-2HG::chr1:29553-31109.E1
```

This explicitly checks for bookends and nothing else and assumes that everything is sorted.